# Create link in email that will redirect to localhost

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create a link in my email body which will open a webpage in asp.net.
I know this website is not yet publish because it's still running on a local host,but is it possible to create a link that will redirect to my webpage while my visual studio is running?

here is my code:

```
 private void send_email()
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        //The email that needs to be checked
        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("******@gmail.com", "Email Check"));
        mm.From = new MailAddress("******@gmail.com");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendFormat(@"
           <h3>We have reviews you transaction</h3>
            <br />
            <br />
            View our reply on Mej website
            <br />
            Enter your transaction code: 
            <br />
            <h2>" + "bla bla"
            + "</h2> Thank you!<br />"
            + "<small>To view your"
            +"transaction please proceed"
            + "<a href='~/Customers/new_web_page/quotation_01.aspx'runat='server'>here</a>"
            +"</small>");

        mm.Body = sb.ToString();
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Subject = "Verification";
        SmtpClient smc1 = new SmtpClient();
        smc1.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smc1.Port = 587;

        smc1.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        smc1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*********@gmail.com", "*********");
        smc1.EnableSsl = true;
        smc1.Send(mm);
    }
```

Here is my error whenever I click the link
[image]

Comment: `~/Customers...` works *within* a website, but for your email you're going to most likely need to provide a fully-qualified URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` statement

```
var href = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Customers/new_web_page/quotation_01.aspx");
```

Change

```
"<a href='~/Customers/new_web_page/quotation_01.aspx'runat='server'>here</a>"
```

to

```
"<a href='" + href + "'>here</a>"
```

Comment: I'm still getting the redirect notice.

Comment: What is the Url now?

Comment: The previous page is sending you to an invalid url (http:///Customers/new_web_page/quotation_01.aspx).

Comment: No. The var statement should go before the StringBuilder statement. Check the updated answer.

Comment: something like this?                                                                             `var href = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Customers/new_web_page/quotation_01.aspx");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`